# Upload photo from gallery or take from camera in Webview

Tags: android, webviewclient, webchromeclient

My application is webbased and need to upload photos, website have a file input button, i made it work with this

```
wv = new WebView(this);
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());  
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()  
{    
         public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture){
               mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;  
               Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
               i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);  
               i.setType("image/*");  
               MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult( Intent.createChooser( i, "File Chooser" ), MainActivity.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE );

}
```

but it shows just gallery to pick photos, i need to take from camera at the same time.

i tried this solution [Upload camera photo and filechooser from webview INPUT field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284903/upload-camera-photo-and-filechooser-from-webview-input-field) but its only opening camera, not uploading taken photo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {      
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView v, String url) { 
     if (url.startsWith("testzapp:")) {
       //do whatever action you had intended
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: i will check it now
** i think its for native apps. I need it in webchromeclient

Comment: make div which show that image. on click of that div return fire some link / url in html. and handle that link in webView Client. Following thing might help you                                          wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()                             {
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView v, String url)      {                                                                  if (url.startsWith("testzapp:"))                                     {}

Comment: this is what i have done in my code . in if condition i check if url which is fired from that link is what i want  then i take the respective action . in your case you write code to get camera service in that if condition and write the code in your web page to upload that image

Comment: i did it like you. but i need help on something else now..
in onActivityResult how can i get url parameter definated in shouldOverrideUrlLoading,  starting with startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);

Comment: @Alper: Can you please tell us how you solved it. I also want to allow user to choose from camera or gallery option in webview. But All i got  is we can either use camera or gallery . have You any Idea how to use both together as you solved it . thanks in advance

Comment: @chirag Nandwani I will edit my question with solution tonight

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution

```
if (url.startsWith("xxx")) {
                String[] falid = url.split(":");
                falidi = Integer.parseInt(falid[1]);
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        "android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
                return true;
            }


public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        final Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE) {
            try {
                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);
                Random randomGenerator = new Random();
                randomGenerator.nextInt();
                newimagename = falidi + "_" + randomGenerator.nextInt()
                        + ".jpg";
                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator + newimagename);
                try {
                    f.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // write the bytes in file

                FileOutputStream fo = null;
                try {
                    fo = new FileOutputStream(f.getAbsoluteFile());
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String uri = f.getAbsolutePath();
                // this is the url that where you are saved the
                // image

                File fx = new File(uri);

                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fx.getPath());
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 30, stream);
                byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
                String image_str = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr,
                        Base64.DEFAULT);

                client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
                        "http://www.xxx.com/android/library/image.php?name="
                                + newimagename);
                List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", image_str));
                try {
                    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Candemir
                new ResultTask().execute(new HttpPost[] { post });
                // Candemir

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```