# Image is uploading from gallery but not from camera through webView

Tags: android, android-intent, webview, upload, android-camera

I'm trying to upload image using webview. Everything works fine as expected but only image is not uploading when photo is clicked from camera. please help me to find this. I got some answer but doesn't help or not answered [like this one is not answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49036661/upload-image-from-camera-in-webview-does-not-work) and [this doesn't help me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725814/upload-an-image-from-camera-or-gallery-in-webview)[this is directly opening gallery not working for camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44042720/choose-image-from-gallery-and-camera-through-web-view-is-not-working-in-android)[this one didn't help me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968787/upload-photo-from-gallery-or-take-from-camera-in-webview)

here is my activity code

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUploadMessages;
    private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;
    private static final int MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        webView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDatabasePath("/data/data/" + webView.getContext().getPackageName() + "/databases/");

        webView.loadUrl("url");

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            // For api level bellow 24
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                if (url.startsWith("http")) {
                    // Return false means, web view will handle the link
                    return false;
                }

                return false;
            }


            // From api level 24
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                /*Toast.makeText(mcontext, "New Method",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

                // Get the tel: url
                String url = request.getUrl().toString();

                if (url.startsWith("http")) {
                    // Return false means, web view will handle the link
                    return false;
                }

                return false;
            }

            // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+

           /* public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                openImageChooser();
            }*/

            // For Lollipop 5.0+ Devices

            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView mWebView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                mUploadMessages = filePathCallback;
                openImageChooser();
                return true;
            }

            // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0

           /* public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
                openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
            }

            //openFileChooser for other Android versions

            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
                openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
            }*/
        });

    }

    private void openImageChooser() {
        try {

            File imageStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "FolderName");

            if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
            }
            File file = new File(imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
            mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);

            final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");

            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Parcelable[]{captureIntent});

            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {

            if (null == this.mUploadMessage && null == this.mUploadMessages) {
                return;
            }

           /* Uri result;
            if (requestCode != RESULT_OK){
                result = null;
            }else {
                result = intent == null ? this.mCapturedImageURI : intent.getData();
            }
            this.mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            this.mUploadMessage = null;*/
            if (null != mUploadMessage) {
                handleUploadMessage(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

            } else if (mUploadMessages != null) {
                handleUploadMessages(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
            }
        }
    }

    private void handleUploadMessage(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        Uri result = null;
        try {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                result = null;
            } else {
                // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null

                result = intent == null ? mCapturedImageURI : intent.getData();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
        mUploadMessage = null;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void handleUploadMessages(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        Uri[] results = null;
        try {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                results = null;
            } else {
                if (intent != null) {
                    String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                    ClipData clipData = intent.getClipData();
                    if (clipData != null) {
                        results = new Uri[clipData.getItemCount()];
                        for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                            ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
                            results[i] = item.getUri();
                        }
                    }
                    if (dataString != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                    }
                } else {
                    results = new Uri[]{mCapturedImageURI};
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mUploadMessages.onReceiveValue(results);
        mUploadMessages = null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine you just need to Add storage and camera permission pragmatically. it will work like charm.

Comment: thanks...this issue was because of storage permission not it's working like charm.

Comment: hey can you please answer my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53741479/how-can-i-make-base-url-dynamically-in-appconstants-class/53742130#53742130)@A.Gun